# Device Emulation for testing

Tags: ios, ipad, webdav

We have a web design agency and we're wanting to test development on an ipad air 2, we have a couple of ipads that we often test our builds on but of course new devices are being regularly being brought to the market that feature newer technology, higher resolution screens etc. and it becomes counterintuitive to possess an endless array of older and new devices for testing on.

So, my question is, what are the currently available services, paid or otherwise, for Apple device emulation?

Comment: You may want to remove the *best* to avoid the question being flagged as "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting Xcode on to your machine. Of course, you don't need to use Xcode itself, but you can use a companion app (it's bundled with Xcode) called iOS Simulator. They have a Safari app that you can open your webpage in.

And, it's free.